To Go the Distance
The boxing metaphor, "to go the distance", is well-known--when the contest lasts to the final round. The phrase is in common use e.g. (foolish) neighbours disputing a few centimetres of garden: ten years fighting in the courts; six-figure legal fees; no guarantee of winning...Going the distance!
In Latin?
Here's a couple of guesses:

"ire ad longinquitatem" = "to go (to) the distance";


"perferre usque ad finem" = "to endure to the end".

Any thoughts?

Does this old question on "go all the way" have what you are looking for?

Of your two options, I much prefer the concrete ad finem to the highly abstract ad longinquitatem. Longiquitas in this context strikes me as pretty strange. I would have a hard time figuring out what you meant, if you hadn't told me.
There is also St. Paul's famous statement near the end of his life: "I have run the race", Cursum consummavi. That might suit your needs, depending on what exactly you are looking for.
